# Array bound violation: segfault at different indices

Tags: arrays, memory-management, segmentation-fault, indexoutofboundsexception

Why does this program segfault on a different value of i every time?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {

  int a[16], i = 0; 
  while(1) {  
    a[i] = i;
    printf("%d\n", a[i]);
    i++;
  }
}
```

Comment: What programming language is this? Is it C? Please tag your question with the language in use. To update your question, click on the **"[edit]"** link under the post. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will be to do with the way C allocates memory. When you use the line

```
int a[16]
```

What you are essentially saying is 'allocate me enough space in memory to hold sixteen integers, starting at a given point (call this point `x`)'.

Then when you say

```
while(1) {  
    a[i] = i;
    printf("%d\n", a[i]);
    i++;
}
```

You say, forever, set the `ith` index of `a` to be `i` and print it. This works by starting at `x` and then moving along, one index at a time. For the first sixteen integers this is fine, as you have cleared the space to do it.

However, when you go past that, you haven't cleared the space, so you don't know what is there and what you can overwrite or print. This might be fine for a while, but then you will come to a point where you can't overwrite what is in memory (it isn't free). At this point you get your `segfault`.

As each time you run the program you will allocate space in a different place, it will take a different number of iterations to reach the point where the memory is taken, and so you will `segfault` at different indexes.

Comment: The explanation for,why does the code not segfault on i = 16, is that the program is not allocated 16 * sizeof(int) bytes of memory, but an entire page on the stack by the operating system.  The hardware detects the page boundary violation and raises interrupt for OS to process, and then the OS sends segmentation signal to the process.  However this still does not explain the different values of i if we run the program multiple times, as the page size given to program will always be the same.

Comment: Can you link where you got that from?

Comment: The whole program is allocated a heap in order for dynamic memory allocation, however this function does not allocate memory dynamically. This function call will use memory from the stack to store local variables. It will allocate a block from the stack of a fixed size (as dynamic memory allocation is done on the heap) and it will determine that size from the size of the array you gave it. Then, when you run over that size you will get the problem above.

Comment: your answer does not explain, why does the program segfault on different values of 'i' every time. It only explains why it does not seg fault at i = 16.

Comment: Because each time the program is run it will allocate the stack at a different place in memory. When the `while` loop runs over the memory allocated to it, it will run into the adjacent memory, which hasn't been allocated to the program. If this is free, then that is fine. However as it runs forever it will eventually reach a point which is not free, which is where it `segfaults`. Because the stack is in a different place each time the amount of free memory adjacent to it changes each time, meaning a different value of `i` for each iteration.